# Regex everything between item tags

Tags: regex, rss

I have an RSS feed and I'm looking for the proper regex to match everything between the `<item>...</item>` tags. I'll then be able to parse out just the data I'm looking for.

Comment: Can you give an example of the string you are trying to parse. What "flavor" of regex are you using? Does it support lookaround? Would a simple expression like `<item>(.*)</item>` not be enough for you (and then your look at just the "thing in parentheses")?

Comment: As you've tagged this as `rss`, why not use an XML parser?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify what language you're working with, but with this regex

`<item>(.+?)<\/item>`

the first match group will contain everything between the <item> tags. That's if they're not nested. If they are, and you want to get all intances -- the inner ones, the outer ones including the inner ones, etc., then you'll need to use a parser, because that's beyond the capabilities of regex.